# Rails and devise user authorisation

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, devise, stripe-payments

I'm trying to implement some super user function in my Rails App. I have setup a couple of free plans with Stripe. I basically want a user that is on plan_id 1 for example, to be able to view the page complete with upload buttons, edit, delete posts buttons, etc, and users on plan_id 2, which will be the majority of users, to only be able to view the posts and uploads and not be able to see the buttons listed above.

Can anyone layout what needs to happen for this to be achieved please? I'm struggling!

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps:

```
# controller
def action_show
  @user = User.current_user
end

def action_admin_only
  @user = User.current_user
  if @user.admin?
    # complete the action
  end
end

private
#Must use strong params

# helper
def current_user
    if (user_id = session[:user_id])
        @current_user ||= User.find_by(id: user_id)
    end
end

# View
<% if user.admin? %>
  <%= link_to "Delete", model_path, method: :delete, class: "button" %>
<% end %>
```